# Unable to load native library on genymotion

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

I'm trying to download PokemonGo and run it on Genymotion. The emulator is Samsung S6 ,6.0.0.
It returns me error like below. Does anyone has any clue?

```
07-15 17:04:23.480 1916-1916/com.nianticlabs.pokemongo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: com.nianticlabs.pokemongo, PID: 1916
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nianticlabs.pokemongo/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/app/com.nianticlabs.pokemongo-1/lib/arm/libmain.so
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/app/com.nianticlabs.pokemongo-1/lib/arm/libmain.so
         at android.app.NativeActivity.onCreate(NativeActivity.java:182)
         at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: haha i have the exactly same problem xD

Comment: Can you see /data/app/com.nianticlabs.pokemongo-1/lib/arm/libmain.so in your emulator? I don't know if you've got an x86 version of the game, or maybe you need to install ARM translation (see e.g. https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-install-google-services-on-genymotion/en).

Comment: @AlexCohn I already install ARM